# According to Roman Catholicism, at what point does original sin affect the human soul?

Tags: catholicism, original-sin, souls

CCC 366 teaches that every soul is immediately created by God and not produced by the parents.

> The Church teaches that every spiritual soul is created immediately by God - it is not "produced" by the parents

CCC 365 states that soul and body are not two separate aspects of man but form an inseparable unity

> in man, are not two natures united, but rather their union forms a single nature.

CCC 404 says that original sin is transmitted by propagation, through the parents, of a deprived human nature

> Adam and Eve committed a personal sin, but this sin affected the human nature that they would then transmit in a fallen state. It is a sin which will be transmitted by propagation to all mankind, that is, by the transmission of a human nature deprived of original holiness and justice.

If human nature is an inseparable unity of body and soul and, if original sin is passed through a deprived human nature, then it must be concluded that, in human nature both body and soul are equally deprived.  If God immediately creates each soul, what is it's state at the moment of it's creation:  Is it A) created already deprived or does it B) share equally in the deprivation of the flesh once united with it?

If A, which I doubt will be the answer, then original sin is imparted to the soul at creation rather than inherited.

If B then it is actually the flesh only that transmits original sin.

Is there a third logical option that this question is missing?

Comment: _The soul that sinneth, it shall die._ Ezekiel 18:20.  The question is : What does a human being do with regard to the sin that is in their flesh by natural generation ? David says _I kept myself from my iniquity_ Psalm 18:23. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Related: [Following the Doctrine in Council of Trent, does God give a soul to human at conception deprived of sanctifying grace?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62722/following-the-doctrine-in-council-of-trent-does-god-give-a-soul-to-human-at-con)

Comment: @remline It is related and seems to indicate option B.

Comment: @NigelJ I guess the answer to that is; take it to the cross and let Jesus break the power of it, forgive my willing participation in it, strengthen me to bear the righteous consequences of it,  provide the Holy Spirit to help guide me away from it, and trust that He has ultimately promised to completely eradicate it from my being.

Comment: @NigelJ  what is a dead soul?

Comment: @Kris Are you asking Ezekiel (in a rhetorical fashion) or did you want my own opinion ?

Comment: @MikeBorden Yes, all of that. And also, see, by faith, that Christ was 'made sin' and removed sin _itself_ in his death, contained within his own humanity as he died.

Comment: @NigelJ  I am asking those who believe in immortality of the soul to explain what Ezekiel 18:20 refers to.   The soul that is eternally tormented is not dead is it?

Comment: @Kris I believe that physical death (the death of the body) is when the heart stops beating. Spiritual death is to be dead to the things of God. If the soul is not awakened (in this life) its spiritual death continues after physical death. Upon the general resurrection the spiritually dead soul is united with the raised body and is consigned to the lake of fire, eternally. This is made very clear in Trinitarian, Protestant, Reformed documentation.

Comment: @NigelJ What sort of life other than spiritual life does a soul have?

Comment: "_at creation rather than inherited._" Why can't original sin be inherited at the moment of a human's creation?

Comment: @Geremia Aquinas, in the answer you linked, appears (but it is not crystal clear as he uses strange phrases like 'power of the semen' and 'motion of the semen is a disposition') to agree with option B; that it is the flesh that propagates original sin and it is the flesh that infects the newly created soul.   Is this why you feel the question is a duplicate?  Incidentally, Aquinas seems to be strongly at odds with the Council of Trent on this matter.

Comment: @Geremia To answer your question "Why can't original sin be inherited at the moment of a human's creation".  It can be if the soul is created ex nihilo by God and the human is created when soul and body are merged (conception for many) but the inheritance has to come through flesh.  If sanctifying grace is what Adam forfeited and that deficit is what we inherit through him, then for God to newly create each soul already with that deficit is not inheritance.  It might be imputation but that's not the language the NT uses.

Comment: @MikeBorden "_Aquinas seems to be strongly at odds with the Council of Trent on this matter_" How so?

Comment: @Geremia Trent indicates God creates a new soul already deprived and Aquinas indicates the soul is infected (deprived) by it's union with the body.

Comment: @Geremia Thank you.

Comment: To be dead means to be apart from Christ, alienated...and strangers...having no hope and without God in the world...being darkened in our understanding, alienated from the life of God because of the ignorance which is in us, because of the hardness of our heart (Eph). There are many types of it: Gen 1:2a; 2:17; 3:6-11; Ezek 18:20; Jn 2:7; 3:15; 4:10; 5:5; 11:6. Ezek 18:20 itself uses the word "soul" as "person" (Ac 2:41; 7:14), so for the "soul to die" there means to die physically, to leave the body. Our soul has its created life. It's made to contain the uncreated life.

Answer (score 1):

## Human soul created and united to the body simultaneously

Pope Pius IX, in his dogmatic definition of the Immaculate Conception, [*Ineffabilis Deus*](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius09/p9ineff.htm), stated that the Blessed Virgin Mother's soul was free from original sin

> *in primo instanti creationis atque infusionis in corpus*
> <sub>in the first instant of [its] creation and infusion into (union with) the body</sub>

"Creation" and "infusion" are simultaneous.

<sup>"*Instanti*" here is the singular ablative of "*insto*" (instant); there is one instant (not one for creation and another for infusion</sup>

This is St. Thomas's teaching, too ([*Summa Theologia* I q. 118 a. 3](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP118.html#FPQ118A3THEP1) co.):

> we must simply confess that souls were not created before bodies, but are created **at the same time** as they are infused into them.
> <sub>simpliciter confitendum est quod animæ non sunt creatæ ante corpora, sed **simul** creantur cum corporibus infunduntur.</sub>

Thus, since there is no duration of time between the soul's creation and union with the body, there is no immaculate soul first and later, once united to the body, a soul stained by original sin.

This doesn't mean God taints the soul with original sin when He creates it, though; [God is not a cause of sin](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS079.html#FSQ79A1THEP1).

Comment: @MikeBorden Are you asking if God intends (except in the case of the Immaculate Conception) to create souls deprived of sanctifying grace?

Comment: But divine intentionality remains even if the direct creation of the soul and the propagation of the flesh are simultaneous.  Is the soul created (by intention) in deficit AND the flesh propagated in deficit or does one affect the other?

Comment: Yes.  Even though the exception need not be brought to bear if sin is propagated in the flesh through Adam (the man) since Mary knew no man.

Comment: Looking at the addition to your answer, it's option B?

Comment: @MikeBorden As [St. Thomas writes](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/62747/1787): "the semen by its own power transmits the human nature from parent to child, and with that nature, the stain which infects it".