# According to Southern Baptists, where does a baby's soul come from?

Tags: nature-of-man, souls, southern-baptist

When someone dies their soul either goes to heaven or to hell, there is no true end for a soul, only for the body because energy cannot be created or destroyed. By the same token, when someone is born their soul couldn't have been created, therefore the soul must have already existed?

At some point in the development of a baby, the ensoulment happens. When exactly this happens is not a universally-agreed-upon thing and may in fact be considered a controversial topic due to the atmosphere around abortions. This entire subject is completely out of the topic of this question.

My question is simply, where does a new human being's soul come from, since it can't have been created?

Since Christianity does not follow the idea of reusing souls, i.e. reincarnation, and souls cannot be created or destroyed, where do "new" souls come from?

Concerning denominations, I am interested in hearing for all, but since one needs to focus on one, I would prefer Southern Baptist.

Comment: @depperm I edited the question to reflect denominations.

Comment: Not completely relevant to the question, but a soul is not "Energy" in the scientific sense, and the fact that Energy cannot be destroyed is not relevant to the question (and also technically Energy can be destroyed, or at last converted to matter). But you are right that most Christians believe that souls are immortal.

Comment: The terms "soul" and "spirit" are sometimes confused within Christianity. The spirit comes from God according to the Bible, but little detail is given. Most baptist/evangelical Christians believe God created the Earth out of nothing, and probably think both each person's spirit is created by God out of nothing.

Comment: Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46753/23657

Comment: @DJClayworth Not the relevant SE site for this type of topic, but no, energy cannot be destroyed. Neither can matter. The conversion of matter -> energy or energy -> matter is not destruction. There would be no loss of mass within the system.

Comment: Seeking information on the 'Southern Baptist Convention' website about what they believe about the soul, I found only a philosophical paper [The Current Soul-Body Debate](https://sbts-wordpress-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/equip/uploads/2015/10/SBJT-V13-N.2_Cooper.pdf) which did not come to any decisive conclusion. The question of matter and energy being indestructible is irrelevant as the soul does not consist of either. A soul is the gift of God - to be given one is to share in his existence, as a spiritual being. Added to that breath-taking gift : is humanity.

Comment: Baptist do not believe in the pre mortal existence of man. Only Jesus only had such. He lived before his earthly life.

Comment: @Kris Good to know. Do you have any resources? Perhaps a scripture reference which is where that knowledge comes from?

Comment: http://www.religionresourcesonline.org/different-types-of-religion/compare/pre-existence.php

Comment: The general consensus among religions that do not believe in pre mortal existence is that at conception,the start of life,the soul begins to exist.

Comment: @TYlerN SUggest you read the Book of John to answer [that question in your comment](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/73679/#comment197421_73679). (which is separate from the question you have asked in your question's text)

Comment: @disciple do you have evidence to support that claim?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I see possibly four claims in my comment. The first is worthy of a new question, which could be too broad. The last is qualified by "probably" because I don't have evidence. Feel free to [ping me in chat](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you wish to discuss any of them.

Comment: "My question is simply, where does a new human being's soul come from, since it can't have been created?" That's a big assumption in there that I don't think coincides with "southern Baptist" theology. "God creates souls" is probably the leading belief among all Christians, by about 95%. LDS have some nuance here, with their pre-existence doctrines, but I think "God creates souls" is still generally true for them too.

Comment: What's also very common is that God *doesn't* (or perhaps can't) *destroy souls*, which is the part you have right. A small set of Christians, maybe 10%, believe God *does* destroy souls.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an untrue assumption in this question...

> My question is simply, where does a new human being's soul come from,
>   since it can't have been created?

Energy cannot be created or destroyed is an atheistic philosophical assumption that presumes there is no God with the ability to create energy.

Southern Baptists for the most part hold the Bible being true and authoritative.  The Bible describes a God who created matter, energy, time, and life.  Although the Bible doesn't answer your question directly as to how a babies soul enters into existence that I know, there's no reason to believe it's existed prior to conception and creating a human soul from nothing is not out of the possibilities of God.  We do know who created them...

> Acts 17:28 for in Him we live and move and exist
>
> John 1:3 All things came into being through Him, and apart from Him
>   nothing came into
>   being that has come into being.

Comment: I agree there is an untrue assumption; however, I disagree that the First Law of Thermodynamics is my untrue assumption: for the faithful, any scientific rule is succeeded by "without the interference of God," i.e. "energy cannot be destroyed [...] without the interference of God." The untrue assumption, I have come to realize is that a soul is energy. A soul does not conform to anything earthly; it is something ethereal, completely unbound to earthly rules, the gift of God; therefore Thermodynamics has absolutely no impact on a soul.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I constantly hear people use the First Law of Thermodynamics as supporting evidence/proof that there is an afterlife for the soul. And I never questioned that argument's validity until recently when someone said, "Then how is a soul created?" My conclusion is that the First Law of Thermodynamics is not a valid argument to support the claim of an afterlife, as earthly laws would have no impact on our souls.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I'm sorry if I was confused.