What is the Biblical Basis for the pre-existence of souls
Recently I learned that there are those who teach the pre-existence of human souls. What is the biblical understanding of the pre-existence of the human soul? Is there any biblical basis for this belief?

Does this answer your question? What does the Bible say about life before conception?

Genesis 2:7 says "And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.".  It says that man became a soul. It doesn't say that man's pre-existing soul was given a physical body.

@RayButterworth That same word used in "breath of life" also means "spirit". God breathed into the man his spirit. https://godrules.net/library/kjvstrongs/kjvstrongsgen2.htm

@pygosceles, yes, but "spirit" and "soul" are not the same thing, and there are several types of spirit.

@RayButterworth The Scripture implies that spirit and body united are properly termed the soul. The spirit by itself may also be termed a soul, albeit an incomplete one in the foregoing sense. Scripture is more than sufficient to prove that the spirit of man existed before mortal birth, and that the spirit of man is the offspring of God.

Your question would be greatly improved if you gave us some more information to work on to show evidence of research you have already done.  For example, which teaching about the pre-existence of souls do you refer to?  And what might be your views on how souls come to exist?

Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46753/23657

Does this answer your question? At what point is a new soul created according to the Catholic Church?

Jeremiah 1:5 is one evidence of what you are looking for:

Before I formed thee in the belly I knew thee; and before thou camest forth out of the womb I sanctified thee, and I ordained thee a prophet unto the nations.

We were known by God before we were born physically. We know the first father and mother of our flesh, and therefore our existence and identity must precede the existence of our physical bodies.
The spirit departs the body at death. Does it not make sense that the spirit also entered the body, giving it life?

The Spirit itself beareth witness with our spirit, that we are the children of God (Romans 8:16)


Furthermore we have had fathers of our flesh which corrected us, and we gave them reverence: shall we not much rather be in subjection unto the Father of spirits, and live? (Hebrews 12:9)


and the dust returns to the ground it came from, and the spirit returns to God who gave it. (Ecclesiastes 12:7)

Our spirits are literal children of God.
The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints teaches as part of God's plan for our salvation that we existed before this Earth life as spirits in the presence of God. We made choices there, and all who came to this Earth having a mortal body chose to follow His plan in premortality, which permitted us to have the privilege of further testing in the flesh. This also explains how Lucifer was cast down from heaven, together with a third of the host of heaven. What host could there be if there had been no creation, or spirit birth?
The devil has no body, which is one reason why he tries to gain access to ours. He is jealous of all the power and enjoyment that comes from having a body. Since his aim is to make us all as miserable as he is, he tempts us to abuse our bodies. The Lord Jesus Christ teaches us how to have fullness of joy by keeping all of God's commandments, and by His mercy, we can be forgiven by repenting fully.
We will also continue to exist for eternity, and the spirit being reunited with the body is the condition of resurrection. It is good logic that what exists forever, namely, the human soul, is eternal, and therefore had no beginning because it has no end. We were clothed upon with bodies of spirit by God our Father before our mortal birth, and later given the further privilege of a body of flesh and bone, which will rise with us in the resurrection, never again to be separated.

Jeremiah refers, specifically, to the 'prophet to all nations'. But in any case, foreknowledge of whom shall exist in the future is not a proof of pre-existence.

@NigelJ This is plainly not referring to "foreknowledge". It is referring to contemporaneous knowledge of a human soul before his birth. Those foreordained to be prophets are not a different kind of being than the rest of us. Nor were those who were cast down.

@pygosceles Out of curiosity are you referring to pre-mortal existence as the Mormons believe according to the fallowing: https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-topics/premortality?lang=eng If so, please show where tis is proved in the Bible? Thank You!

@Mr.Bond If you wish to know, begin by sincerely reading the foregoing references.

@pygosceles What foregoing references are you referring to? If you mean the LDS site I referenced my question still stands. Where is this taught in the Bible? Btw, I read everything "sincerely." I was not aware that you know the operation of one's mind to know if a person is sincere or not. I don't play games around here because all of these discussions have life and death consequences.Something you should keep in mind.

@Mr.Bond As in, any and all of the sample of references included in the answer you are commenting on. The invitation to be sincere is not the preclusion of existing sincerity. It is simply an admonition of what is required.
